# AppHangB1 trying to bring an Outlook.Explorer to the fore

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, outlook

We have an application that may under some circumstances launch Outlook. It gets an Outlook.Explorer object (oWindow As Outlook.Explorer) and calls its .Activate() procedure.

Up to that point all is hunky dory, but then I want to bring the Explorer object to the foreground, and we call this procedure:

```
Public Shared Sub BringToFore(ByVal oWindow As Object)

    Dim oFoo As IOleWindow
    Dim hWnd As IntPtr

    oFoo = TryCast(oWindow, IOleWindow)
    If Not (oFoo Is Nothing) Then
        Try
            oFoo.GetWindow(hWnd)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End If

    Try
        If hWnd.ToInt32 <> IntPtr.Zero.ToInt32 Then
            Try
                If IsIconic(hWnd) Then
                    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_RESTORE)
                End If
                SetForegroundWindow(hWnd)
            Catch ex As System.Exception

            End Try
        Else

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

IOleWindow is defined as follows:

```
<ComImport(), Guid("00000114-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)> _
Private Interface IOleWindow
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Returns the window handle to one of the windows participating in in-place activation
    ''' (frame, document, parent, or in-place object window).
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="phwnd">Pointer to where to return the window handle.</param>
    Sub GetWindow(<System.Runtime.InteropServices.Out()> ByRef phwnd As IntPtr)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Determines whether context-sensitive help mode should be entered during an
    ''' in-place activation session.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="fEnterMode"><c>true</c> if help mode should be entered;
    ''' <c>false</c> if it should be exited.</param>
    Sub ContextSensitiveHelp(<[In](), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> ByVal fEnterMode As Boolean)
End Interface
```

and the usual declarations

```
Private Const SW_RESTORE As Integer = 9
Private Declare Auto Function IsIconic Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As Boolean
Private Declare Auto Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Long
Private Declare Auto Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As Integer) As IntPtr
```

The BringToFore procedure works fine most of the time. And sometimes the calling application - a WPF application - just hangs. The Event Viewer records an AppHangB1 and the application crashes.

Is there anything I can do in the BringToFore procedure to prevent this happening? Any idea which of these are causing the problem? TryCast(oWindow, IOleWindow), oFoo.GetWindow(hWnd), IsIconic(hWnd), ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_RESTORE) or SetForegroundWindow(hWnd)? (I personally suspect it may be SetForegroundWindow, to be honest). If so, is there anything I can do in the code? Some condition to check? If *this* condition is true then don't try to do *that* ..... sort of thing? I'd rather not go as far as just abandoning the idea of setting the Explorer to the foreground; in that circumstance Outlook may appear "behind" my application and some users may just not realise that something has happened.... if you catch my drift.

Thanks

Pino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this issue would require more debugging. I found a similar issue posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706649/what-can-cause-a-wpf-application-to-crash-with-an-apphangb1-problem-event-name) quite a few years back with a suggestion which might be useful to get to the root cause.

Comment: Thanks Joshg345 but I'm not sure the scenario matches. According to our user our application closed of its own accord, not because she tried to close out of it as suggested in your thread. The suggested link on the page appears to be dead but I'll go searching for Windbg

Comment: ok google is indeed our friend and I found more up to date links for Windbg. Thanks Josh

Answer (score 1):

Windows would prevent you from using `SetForegroundWindow` if the window belongs to a process other than the active one. You'd need to call `AttachThreadInput` first. Here is the function (Delphi):

```
function ForceForegroundWindow(hWnd: THandle): BOOL;
var
  hCurWnd: THandle;
begin
  hCurWnd := GetForegroundWindow;
  AttachThreadInput(
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hCurWnd, nil),
    GetCurrentThreadId, True);
  Result := SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
  AttachThreadInput(
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hCurWnd, nil),
    GetCurrentThreadId, False);
end;
```

Comment: Hello Dmitry - sorry for the late reply; I was on annual leave! That sounds VERY promising indeed and I will investigate same.

Regards

Comment: Well, I implemented AttachThreadInput as suggested and so far on my own system in debug mode it all still runs perfectly. Now I'll have to try the same thing on the customer's machine... but this looks promising! Thanks Dmitry!

Comment: Just one question though.... Why would this not simply ALWAYS fail? Instead, it appears to work most of the time, but fail occasionally with that dreaded AppHangB1 error? Anyhooooooo.... will test this on site now.

Comment: After further testing it appears to happen when outlook starts up showing a dialog; this could be the "a program is trying to access" dialog that ClickYes was written for, or a "server is unavailable wait / retry / cancel " one, or even a Reminder popping up as the Outlook.Application is created and made visible.

I've now farmed off this functionality into a thread separate to the main UI thread. So far it's looking good. I have, however, kept your AttachThreadInput in place as it seems a good idea regardless.